# Chrome Extension - is popup.html exist in it's own isolated DOM?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

Given a popup.html construction in a chrome extension, is it possible for a webpage (using jquery for example) to "read" elements that are in the popup's DOM?  I know through the API the popup.js can ask for elements in the main tab's DOM, but I'm not sure if it's possible for information to pass the other way.

I'm hoping it's built like a one-way street...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The popup is isolated from webpages. Webpages have no direct access to a popup's DOM.